# General boundary conditions

Tags: fipy

I’d appreciate help on setting general boundary conditions, `-grad(y) + g(y) = 0` where `g` is some function of the unknown `y`.  Here’s a simple 1D example that I can’t get to work:

```
N=3
h=1./(float(N)-1.)

mesh = Grid1D(nx=N, dx=h)

c=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,value=0.5)

## Dirichlet boundary conditions
#c.constrain(2., mesh.facesLeft)
#c.constrain(1., mesh.facesRight)

## Neumann boundary conditions
c.faceGrad.constrain(-1, where=mesh.facesLeft)
c.faceGrad.constrain( -c.faceValue , where=mesh.facesRight)

Eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=1.0)
Eq.cacheMatrix()
Eq.cacheRHSvector()
Eq.solve(var=c)
m = Eq.matrix.numpyArray
b = Eq.RHSvector
```

This code won’t solve but I do get to see the matrix and RHS:

```
m= array([[-2.,  2.,  0.],
          [ 2., -4.,  2.],
          [ 0.,  2., -2.]])

b= array([-1. ,  0. ,  0.5])
```

The matrix, `m`, is clearly singular because the source term was not included in the last line. Any suggestions on how to include it?

Answer (score 0):

[edit: add derivation and demonstration of 1st order implementation]

There are [known issues](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/426#issuecomment-61322554) with general boundary conditions.

It is possible to implement such a boundary condition as a source. Using the [discretization of the DiffusionTerm](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/numerical/discret.html#diffusion-term) `$\sum_f D_f (n\cdot\nabla(y))_f A_f$` we treat `$f=R$` as a special case and substitute of the desired boundary condition `-n\cdot\nabla(y) - y = 0`. We accomplish this by zeroing `D_(f=R)` in the `DiffusionTerm`

```py
c.faceGrad.constrain([-1], where=mesh.facesLeft)

D = 1.
Dface = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=D)
Dface.setValue(0., where=mesh.facesRight)
```

and then adding an implicit source `D_(f=R) (n\cdot\nabla(y))_(f=R) A_(f=R)` or `D_(f=R) (-y)_(f=R) A_(f=R)`. Sources are defined at cell centers, so we locate the cell adjacent to `$f=R$`

```py
mask_coeff = (mesh.facesRight * mesh.faceNormals).divergence
```

and then add the source

```py
Af = mesh._faceAreas[mesh.facesRight.value][0]
Eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dface) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=mask_coeff * D * Af)
```

This treatment is only 0th order accurate as the `ImplicitSourceTerm` operates on the value at the cell center, whereas the boundary condition is defined at the adjacent face center.

We can make the boundary condition 1st order accurate in space by projecting the cell value to the face along the gradient from the boundary condition: 
`y_(f=R) ~ y_P + n\cdot\nabla(y)_(f=R) dPR` where `y_P` is the value of `y` at the cell center closest to `f=R` and `dPR` is the distance from point `P` to face `R`.

Thus the boundary condition `-n\cdot\nabla(y)_(f=R) - y_(f=R) = 0` becomes `-n\cdot\nabla(y)_(f=R) - (y_P + n\cdot\nabla(y)_(f=R) dPR) = 0`, which we can solve for `n\cdot\nabla(y)_(f=R) = -y_P / (1 + dPR)`. The implicit source corresponding to the boundary for the `DiffusionTerm` is thus `D_(f=R) (-y_P / (1 + dPR)) A_(f=R)`

```py
dPR = mesh._cellDistances[mesh.facesRight.value][0]
Af = mesh._faceAreas[mesh.facesRight.value][0]
Eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dface) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=mask_coeff * D * Af / (1 + dPR))
```

This was discussed last summer on the FiPy mailing list, starting at https://www.mail-archive.com/fipy@nist.gov/msg03671.html. Yes, it's all pretty clumsy right now.

Comment: Thanks, that does appear to get closer. However, it's not clear to me how the flux term is introduced, perhaps it has something to do with the divergence attribute? This approach also seems to constrain the face values and cell center values to be equal at the boundary. (See [this plot](http://imgur.com/a/jJz3M) for the above example.) This introduces an error that scales with cell size.

Comment: I had a feeling you would want to know why the source looks like that. Good excuse for me to figure out why it looks like that. I've edited my answer to describe the derivation and give a better extrapolation to the boundaries.