# Translate 2-D PDEs and conditions into accurate Fipy codes

Tags: 2d, fipy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86cIR.png)

The image includes the control equation,initial and boundary condition.It descripe a heat transfer problem between a plate and fluid.
I don't know how to use fipy to encode the 2-d problem and boundary condition that include the var.
Here is my attempt.

```
from fipy import *
import numpy as np
#constant
Pe=2400
le_L=1/20000
L_l=20000
alphas=1
alphaf=1
a=1/Pe+le_L
b=1/Pe+L_l
Bi=0.4
c=Bi/Pe*L_l
#generate
mesh=Grid2D(dx=1,dy=1)
Ts=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,name='Ts',value=900)
Tf=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,name='Tf',value=300)
#condition
Ts.faceGrad.constrain([0.],mesh.facesLeft)
Ts.faceGrad.constrain([0.],mesh.facesRight)
Ts.faceGrad.constrain([-1.*Bi*(Tf.value-Ts.value)],mesh.facesBottom)
Ts.faceGrad.constrain([0.],mesh.facesTop)

Tf.constrain(300,mesh.facesLeft)
Tf.grad.constrain(0,mesh.facesRight)



a=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,rank=1)
a[:]=1

#eq
eq1=TransientTerm(var=Ts)==DiffusionTerm(coeff=[[a,b]],var=Ts)
eq2=TransientTerm(var=Tf)==DiffusionTerm(coeff=[[a,0]],var=Tf)-       
ExponentialConvectionTerm(a,var=Tf)+ImplicitSourceTerm(c,var=Tf)-         
ImplicitSourceTerm(c,var=Ts)

eq=eq1&eq2

#solve
dt=0.1
steps=100
viewer=Viewer(vars=(Ts,Tf),datamax=1000,datamin=0)
for i in range(steps):
eq.solve(dt=dt)
viewer.plot()
```

I find it failed.And I don't know where goes wrong.I would welcome any help; many thanks!
BTW,the final image i wish to get is like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex3Uo.png)
......Many thx!

Answer (score 1):

[edited to fix general boundary conditions]

The following runs and seems to give results of the nature you're looking for:

```
from fipy import *
import numpy as np
#constant
Pe=2400.
le_L=1./20000.
L_l=20000.
alphasx=alphasy=1.
alphaf=1.
Bi=0.4
c=Bi/Pe*L_l

Dsxx = alphasx
Dsyy = alphasy * L_l**2
Ds = 1./Pe * le_L * (1./alphaf) * Variable([[alphasx, 0.], 
                                            [0., alphasy * L_l**2]])

Df = Variable([[1./Pe * le_L, 0],
               [0., 0.]])

#generate
mesh=Grid2D(Lx=1.,Ly=1.,nx=100, ny=100)
Ts=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,name='Ts',value=900.)
Tf=CellVariable(mesh=mesh,name='Tf',value=900.)
#condition
bottom_mask = (mesh.facesBottom * mesh.faceNormals).divergence
dPR = mesh._cellDistances[mesh.facesBottom.value][0]
Af = mesh._faceAreas[mesh.facesBottom.value][0]
bottom_coeff = bottom_mask * Ds[1,1] * Af / (1 + dPR)

Tf.constrain(300,mesh.facesLeft)



#eq
eq1=(TransientTerm(var=Ts)==DiffusionTerm(coeff=Ds,var=Ts)
     + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=bottom_coeff * -Bi, var=Tf)
     - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=bottom_coeff * -Bi, var=Ts))
eq2=(TransientTerm(var=Tf)==DiffusionTerm(coeff=Df,var=Tf)
    -ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=[[1.], [0]],var=Tf)
     +ImplicitSourceTerm(c,var=Tf)
     -ImplicitSourceTerm(c,var=Ts))

eq=eq1&eq2

#solve
dt=0.01
steps=100
viewer=Viewer(vars=(Ts,Tf),datamax=1000,datamin=0)
for i in range(steps):
    eq.solve(dt=dt)
    viewer.plot()
```

- I changed a number of coefficients to agree with the mathematics you provided.
- I fixed the diffusion coefficients to have the shape expected by FiPy for anistropic diffusion
- I changed lots of ints to floats because ints don't work well in FiPy
- I provided a domain to solve over (your mesh only had a single cell in it, making spatial variation impossible)
- I decreased the time step
- I introduced the best way we know how to deal with [general boundary conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769749/general-boundary-conditions). It's ugly, but I think it's right.

You will probably also want to introduce sweeping to account for the nonlinear dependency between the equations and the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks! You mean the way you introduce by defining boundary as source term can avoid the sweeping?Can i add the boundary condition into the 'for' cycle to update,like: for i in range(steps): Ts.faceGrad.constrain([-1.*Bi*(Tf.value-Ts.value)],mesh.face‌​sBottom);；eq1=TransientTerm(var=Ts)==DiffusionTerm(Ds,var=Ts)； eq2=TransientTerm(var=Tf)==DiffusionTerm(Df,var=Tf)-Exponent‌​ialConvectionTerm([[‌​1.], [0]],var=Tf)+ImplicitSourceTerm(c,var=Tf)-ImplicitSourceTerm‌​(c,var=Ts)； eq=eq1&eq2； eq.solve(dt=dt) viewer.plot()

Comment: Sweeping may not be necessary. I don't think there are any nonlinear dependencies in your equations/boundary conditions. The linear dependencies should be handled by the coupled solve. I do not think that calling `.constrain()` over and over in the loop is a good idea. The sources as I wrote are our best recommendation for general boundary conditions right now.

Comment: I have learned about the method.But the prototype of this problem is **heat transfer from the bottom of a rectangular solid to the top of fluid**.So I code `mask= (m.facesTop * m.faceNormals).divergence
dPR = m._cellDistances[m.facesTop.value][0]
Af = m._faceAreas[m.facesTop.value][0]
coeff_top = mask*Df[1,1]*Af/(1+dPR)`for the top of fluid,and use `eq1=TransientTerm(var=Ts)==DiffusionTerm(coeff=Ds,var=Ts)\
     + ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=top_coeff * -Bi, var=Tf)\
     - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=bottom_coeff * -Bi, var=Ts)`for the first equationBut it doesn't work well...Where is wrong?

Comment: "it doesn't work well" doesn't give much to go on. What happens? What do you expect to happen? That being said, I don't think it makes sense to try to collocate solid and liquid in the same domain. top_coeff is being evaluated at the top of both the solid and the liquid and bottom_coeff is evaluated at the bottom of both the solid and the liquid. This separation in space does not represent conduction from the top of the liquid to the bottom of the solid. I recommend creating a domain that physically places solid above liquid.

Comment: I want to represent the conduction from the bottom of solid to the top of liquid ,and by regulating the constant expected result is like [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhrDU.png).You said 'creating a domain that places solid above liquid'.And how to describle Tf and Ts in different place of a mesh?

Comment: Temperature is temperature. Tf is the temperature in the part of your domain that is fluid. Ts is the temperature in the part of your domain that is solid.